# Access: change subform based on button press

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

Im pretty new to programming for MS Access and Visual basic. I'm trying to create a form that will change what the subform is based on a toggled option press.

I have attached pictures of the simple form I'm trying to do and gotten some code off tutorial sites that have shown an example of how to do it but I'm not sure if I should have the subforms pre-created or make the button load the form when clicked.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Option0_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Toggle11_GotFocus()
Form1!Testform1.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Toggle12_GotFocus()
Form1!Testform2.SetFocus
End Sub
```

I know this code isn't all that's needed but I can't seem to find a good place to start to find out what needs to be done with this.

[image: Sample form]

Comment: Add a tab control that contains your subforms then switch between tabs when your button is clicked.

Comment: Looks like you want a navigation control. That does this exactly, and is easy to build using the GUI. While you can implement a navigation control yourself using buttons and subforms, I strongly recommend you just use the default

Comment: so would the navigation control work if i wanted it to go to different tables. and where would i go to find out how to set one up

Comment: *In response to comment question abt Navigation Control*: Search the web for "Access Navigation Control".  I just did it and got at least 3 useful resources and even a tutorial at the top of the results.  (And this is not meant as a snarky answer.  **I always do a web search myself** before looking for questions on SO.  Actually, I usually do multiple web searches, trying alternative terms, etc.  I am only advising what I would do, even if it seems like the obvious, lazy answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Access seem to hide subform tabs when you open a form, but there is a tab stop property for the childforms.  I set the property for that to yes and then  for one of the child forms to set the tab index to 0 and the other to 1.  You can toggle between the forms using Ctrl Tab when you do this.  If the Child Form tabs are not visible when you open the main form, Ctrl Tab will also make them visible allowing you to click on the tabs.